# O que devo fazer quando uma pergunta é cross-posted?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, comunidade

Esta é eventualmente uma dúvida que eu deveria colocar no [metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), mas achei bem colocar aqui para haver também uma referencia em português.

Eu não estou especificamente a falar de perguntas que também se encontram no SOEN.

O que devo fazer quando a pergunta é cross-posted? Ou seja, quando ela é postada em mais que uma comunidade.

Comment: Acho que não tem problema nenhum, minhas ultimas perguntas mesmo eu retirei do SOEn, lógico que não dei um control+C no tradutor e colei aqui, mas a duvida eu retirei de la e adaptei com minhas palavras. Não vejo mal nisso, muito pelo contrario, enriquece soluções boas no nosso idioma, ainda mais quando não se sabe inglês. Como o Gabe me falou uma vez, não pode é abusar e querer traduzir tudo de la pra ca.

Comment: Imagino que isso responde, não? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125/101

Comment: Acho que é duplicada de: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3832/129, ou de essa ^ que o @bigown referiu.